# How add li to ul dynamically through jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, carousel

This is my jsp code :

```
<div class="demo-1">
    <ul id="carousel"></ul>
</div>
```

To add in this `li` dynamically to `ul` I'm am using jquery :

```
$('#carousel').append('<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"'+img.toString()+'\" alt=\"image03\"/></a></li>');
carousel.add();
carousel.slideEnd();
```

But whenever I am getting a new image its not appending to the last one instead of that it is showing the first one every time.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You want [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) - it inserts as the first child.

> ## **.prepend()**
>
> **Description:** Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the
>   beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$('#carousel').prepend($('<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"'+img.toString()+'\" alt=\"image03\"/></a></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#carousel').
    prepend('<li><a href=\"#\"><img src=\"'+img.toString()+'\" alt=\"image03\"/></a></li>');
```